# Paging issue in ExtJS 4.1

Tags: extjs, paging, extjs4.1

I have figure out that when the grid has paging property you should not sent the metaData property second time from the server. Because if you send it second time paging breaks. I only needs to send at first. How should I overcome this problem? The problem comes from this code that I have found it in the documentation.

```
listeners: { //under the store
            'metachange': function(store,meta){
            grid.reconfigure(store,meta.columns);
            }
```

Comment: I'm not sure the question is clear enough. Can't you simply not return the metaData from the server if the request has a page different than 1?

Comment: @Izhaki, I have tried it but when the user comes back to page 1 the paging breaks everything.

Comment: And no way to have two server calls: one you only do once to get the meta data, the other to do read?

Comment: @Izhaki, I think I have to send the meta parameter only once.

Comment: By the way, it will hep if you mention where in the documentation you have found the code you are providing? Is it part of the ExtJS library or is it an example you're copying?

Comment: @Izhaki, this is from the MetaData Response section of http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json

Comment: OK, that's sample code which you had to add to your app. See my proposal below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proposal:

```
listeners: { //under the store
    'metachange': function(store,meta){
     if ( !this.meta )
     {
         this.meta = meta;
         grid.reconfigure(store,meta.columns);
     }
}
```